# Find value groups in a numpy array and calculate the distance between them

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, grouping

I have a huge numpy 2D array. I'd like to find groups of points with the same values and find the distance of the closest similar group. An example:

```
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 12  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0 12 12  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0 12 12 12 12  0  0
0  0  0  0  0 12 12 12 12  0  0  0
0  0  0  0 12 12 12 12  0  0  0  0
0  0 12 12 12 12 12  0  0  0  0  0
0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20 20 20  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20 20  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0 14 14  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0 14 14  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

In this case, I've three groups: 12, 20, and 14. I´d like to find the groups, then calculate the minimum distance between them. In the case of 12th group, the closest is the 20th group, and the distance will be `sqrt(2^2+4^2)=4.47`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you know how sparse this array is?

Comment: I´ts sparse, but so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use dilation with circular kernel of a fixed radius. Next, if there is a non-zero point that changed a group then memorize its former and updated group. Use bisection to select a new radius. You will a minimal radius and a relevant pair of groups after log(size) iterations.